# regular languages/expressions capturing all numbers in exponential notation

Tags: regex, regular-language

I'm trying to write a regular expression that captures all numbers in exponential notation.   The notation consists of a numeral followed by a period (.), followed by one more digits, followed by E or e, followed possibly by -, followed by a numberal. By the way I cannot write out (1-9)... I have to write out (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)

example

```
3.022E24 or 3.022e24 = 3.022 x 10^24
1.4e-22 = 1.4 x 10^-22
```

what I think it is.

```
(0+(1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9)*).(0+1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9)*(E+e)(-+ε)(0+(1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9)*)
```

This would be correct right?  I'm thinking way to hard on how to go about this...  Any tips or pointers I would appreciate.

Comment: What do you mean by that : By the way I cannot write out (1-9)... I have to write out (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)

Answer (score 0):

```
 (0+(1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9)*)
```

gives you a zero or a number that does not contain any zeroes. Probably you want:

```
 (0+((1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9)(0+1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9)*))
```

If you do not want trailing zeroes after the comma, use:

```
 (0+((0+1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9)*(1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9)))
```

This allows one zero after the comma. This seems to be the solution you want for numbers that do not have a decimal part like  2.0e3.